# Error connecting remote Linux Server using VSCode

Tags: linux, ssh, vscode-remote

I tried to connect to remote Linux server, and
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbCGG.png) occurs.

Below is the output log:

```
[16:15:30.450] Opening exec server for ssh-remote+linux9
[16:15:30.517] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+linux9
[16:15:30.533] Using commit id "8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314" and quality "stable" for server
[16:15:30.535] Install and start server if needed
[16:15:30.625] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\lenovo\.ssh\config"
[16:15:30.626] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -o ClearAllForwardings=true -F "C:\Users\lenovo\.ssh\config" linux9 bash
[16:15:30.628] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[16:15:32.059] "install" terminal command done
[16:15:32.060] Install terminal quit with output: 
[16:15:32.060] Exec server for ssh-remote+linux9 failed: Error: Got bad result from install script
[16:15:32.060] Error opening exec server for ssh-remote+linux9: Error: Got bad result from install script
```

I found out that If I connect to other servers using VSCode, this problem also occurs.

However, I have tried to connect using Termius which is another SSH tool and it is successful.

Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting one of the registry key-value pair:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor: autorun

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).